# Unable to set drawable as background on a textview in api 19

Tags: android

```
myTextView.setBackground(getContext().getDrawable(R.drawable.bubble_right_green));
```

This code works on API 23 but crashes when i run it on API 19, following is the log:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.content.Context.getDrawable
 at com.example.msp.legaldesire.Chat_Room_Adapter.getView(Chat_Room_Adapter.java:56)
```

I also tried

```
android:background="@drawable/bubble_right_green"
```

This also works perfectly on API 23 but on API 19 i get this:

```
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                   Process: com.example.msp.legaldesire, PID: 14272
                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class TextView
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                             at com.example.msp.legaldesire.Chat_Room_Adapter.getView(Chat_Room_Adapter.java:46)
```

I am getting error at lin 46:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_room_adapter, null);
```

I need to know why this happens on api 19 and not on 23. Also possible solutions to set drawable as a background for a textview.

EDIT :
after some suggestions i used

```
setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_right_green);
```

i got this error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.msp.legaldesire, PID: 5041
                                                                       android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02004c
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2342)
                                                                           at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1907)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable(ResourcesWrapper.java:128)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:45)
                                                                           at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16251)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.setBackgroundResource(AppCompatTextView.java:73)
                                                                           at com.example.msp.legaldesire.Chat_Room_Adapter.getView(Chat_Room_Adapter.java:56)
```

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:gravity="center"
   <!-- android:background="@drawable/bubble_right_green"  //ERROR -->
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

my drawable that i'm trying to add as background:
[bubble_right_green.9.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GWXu.png)

Comment: use `setBackgroundResource()`

Comment: Please add your xml layout code and bubble_right_green drawable to find out the main issue

Comment: so what is `R.drawable.bubble_right_green`? does it even exist? did you try to clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: Yes it exist, it is in the drawable folder, like i said my other device running API 23 works perfectly with R.drawable.bubble_right_green as textview background but API 19 is giving me issues

Comment: Let's do a try...Use other drawable rather than bubble_right_green.9.png and check is it working or not?

Comment: drawables with .xml extensions are working, .png extensions are crashing tha app @ReadyAndroid

Comment: did you try to clean and rebuild your project? or even remove the whole `build` folder?

Comment: cleaned and rebuilt @pskink, the error persist

Comment: no, there is not, otherwise no app would work in api 19

Answer (score 0):

You can use method setBackgroundResource instead of setBackground. Because method getDrawable of Context class is add from API 21 (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDrawable(int))

```
myTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_right_green)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use these hope this will work fine.!

textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sample_image);

Answer (score 0):

This is really weird. As you are saying xml is working for you then let a try to do in this way, may be this will help you.

Create an xml in drawable directory: **bg_bubble_right_green.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bubble_right_green" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bubble_right_green" android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/bubble_right_green" />
</selector>
```

Now try to use this xml to your TextView as a background, like:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_bubble_right_green"
        android:gravity="center" />
```

**OR**

```
txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_bubble_right_green);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this method i didn't tried this but i hope it works

```
 txt.setBackgroundResource(int rsid);
txt.setBakgroundDrawable(Drawable object);
txt.setBackgroundColor(color id);
```

The most suitable is txt.setBackgroundResource(int rsid); where you can directly set your image from drawable folder as below:

```
txt.setBakgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked, but i want the bubble_right_green.png as my textview background

Comment: For setting backgroud image you can try this txt.setBakgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);